# Volley Request (Request Code missing)

Tags: android, android-volley

I was comparing the Volley Libs (the old one I had and the latest one [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley))

Below is whats used for instantiating the Request (Request.java class)

//Old code

```
public Request(int method, String url, Response.ErrorListener listener,int requestCode) {
    mMethod = method;
    mUrl = url;
    mErrorListener = listener;
    mRequestCode = requestCode;
    setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy());

    mDefaultTrafficStatsTag = TextUtils.isEmpty(url) ? 0: Uri.parse(url).getHost().hashCode();
}
```

//Current code

```
public Request(int method, String url, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
    mMethod = method;
    mUrl = url;
    mIdentifier = createIdentifier(method, url);
    mErrorListener = listener;
    setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy());

    mDefaultTrafficStatsTag = findDefaultTrafficStatsTag(url);
}
```

What came to my surprise is something I have been using very prominently. the **requestCode** variable missing in the new one using which I used to identify my response or error belongs to which Request.

A new variable **mIdentifier** has been introduced which I thought might be the replacement, but couldn't find anything about it.

Also, I found the `setTag()` method being used on the Request object but that's only for cancelling the request, [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html).

Any suggestion or help on how I can implement the same requestCode thing or a workaround to get the same functionality in the new code will be great.

Thanks. :)

Sample: Below is the way response and error callbacks were handled. Missing the **type** params in the old code.

//Old code

```
/** Callback interface for delivering parsed responses. */
public interface Listener<T> {
    /** Called when a response is received. */
    public void onResponse(T response,int type);

    /**
     * On response headers.
     *
     * @param headers the headers
     */
    public void onResponseHeaders(Map<String, String> headers,int type);
}

/** Callback interface for delivering error responses. */
public interface ErrorListener {
    /**
     * Callback method that an error has been occurred with the
     * provided error code and optional user-readable message.
     */
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error,int type);
}
```

//Current code

```
/** Callback interface for delivering parsed responses. */
public interface Listener<T> {
    /** Called when a response is received. */
    public void onResponse(T response);
}

/** Callback interface for delivering error responses. */
public interface ErrorListener {
    /**
     * Callback method that an error has been occurred with the
     * provided error code and optional user-readable message.
     */
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error);
}
```

Edit (I will like to achieve the below in the new code rather than writing the response every single time I create a request):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Object response, int type) {     

    if (type == NetworkController.REQ_CODE_UPDATE_USER) {
        //Update user
    }else if(type == NetworkController.REQ_CODE_DELETE_USER){
        //Delete User
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need `requestCode` to identify the request?

Comment: Suppose I have two request in the same screen then I will write request = new Request and the entire response and error code at the same place. This I have to repeat for the 2nd req. However using requestCode what I can do is just pass the context to the reponse parameter while calling the request and then in the onResponse method which I will override after implementing the Response Listener I can do if requestCode == 1st request do this else that. Hope you get the picture here.

Comment: to me it looks like you want to avoid the creation of different instance of the Listener

Comment: yes,  u got my point.

Comment: this way you are tightly coupling two unrelated things. Benefit 0. Have a different Listener for each different backend call

Comment: still you can subclass Request and Response to get that value. It shouldn't be that hard

Comment: I have kept my business logic separate from the code, so its a static method in my businessLogic class where in I only pass the params and context and in my Activity or Fragment I only handle the response. I thaught this was de-coupling. :( Please correct me where I m going wrong about it. Also, how do I subclass?

Comment: to subclass you need your class `MyRequest extends Request` and implement the abstracts method

Comment: @AtulOHolic, do you want to get the HTTP status code on the server answers, right ?

Answer (score 2):

If i understood correctly, you wanted to maintain a single response listener for all the requests you create. Then you can implement a custom listener like below and store the reqcode for each request and handle the response based on reqcode.

```
class MyResponseListener implements Response.Listener<String> {
            int reqCode;
            public MyResponseListener(int reqcode){
                reqCode = reqcode;
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(reqCode  == 1){
                    Log.v("myapp","inside req code 1");
                    tv1.setText("hello world");
                }else if(reqCode == 2){
                    Log.v("myapp","inside req code 2");
                    tv2.setText("hello world2");
                }
            }
        }
```

Create a Request as below.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new MyResponseListener(1), new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                }
            });

            StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new MyResponseListener(2), new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                }
            });
```

I Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks @7383. However in this case i will have to create this inner class everywhere I want to use it, isn't it? :(

Comment: Yes of course. This is better than older approach where you end up creating multiple anonymous classes to handle the response. But in this case you have only one class which will handle different responses.

Comment: Are you looking for some thing more? above answer does not solve your issue?

Comment: the volley library itself is very stable. I am only trying to build a wrapper on top of it so that I can simplyfy the calling. I guess I will have to override Request class.

Comment: ok Fine, Please upvote the answer if you feel it is helpful as you know voting is important to improve reputations:-)

Comment: I will offer you the bounty as well :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81148/discussion-between-atul-o-holic-and-7383).